# .bulkDelete() count messages deleted

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have figured out how to use Discord.JS's .bulkDelete() but how would I go about counting the messages deleted?

Sorry for the brief question, if you want more information, comment and I will add it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of bulkDelete it doesn't return a value

https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/4520c801d370708bc1d914bfa2d9b61729dbdf1e/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js#L354

```
 /**
   * Bulk delete given messages that are newer than two weeks.
   * <warn>This is only available when using a bot account.</warn>
   * @param {Collection<Snowflake, Message>|Message[]|number} messages Messages or number of messages to delete
   * @param {boolean} [filterOld=false] Filter messages to remove those which are older than two weeks automatically
   * @returns {Promise<Collection<Snowflake, Message>>} Deleted messages
   */
  bulkDelete(messages, filterOld = false) {
    if (!isNaN(messages)) return this.fetchMessages({ limit: messages }).then(msgs => this.bulkDelete(msgs, filterOld));
    if (messages instanceof Array || messages instanceof Collection) {
      let messageIDs = messages instanceof Collection ? messages.keyArray() : messages.map(m => m.id);
      if (filterOld) {
        messageIDs = messageIDs.filter(id =>
          Date.now() - Snowflake.deconstruct(id).date.getTime() < 1209600000
        );
      }
      return this.client.api.channels[this.id].messages['bulk-delete']
        .post({ data: { messages: messageIDs } })
        .then(() =>
          this.client.actions.MessageDeleteBulk.handle({
            channel_id: this.id,
            ids: messageIDs,
          }).messages
        );
    }
    throw new TypeError('MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE');
  }
```

All you can do is recreate the bulk delete function, or extend the object you're using with your own function to return the number of files that are eglible for the bulk delete.

something along the lines of(untested):

```
findEglibleForDeletion(messages, filterOld = false) {
if (!isNaN(messages)) return this.fetchMessages({ limit: messages }).length;
if (messages instanceof Array || messages instanceof Collection) {
  let messageIDs = messages instanceof Collection ? messages.keyArray() : messages.map(m => m.id);
  if (filterOld) {
    messageIDs = messageIDs.filter(id =>
      Date.now() - Snowflake.deconstruct(id).date.getTime() < 1209600000
    );
  }
  return messageIDs.length;
}
throw new TypeError('MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE');
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for that; should I put this in the TextBasedChannel.js, and if I should; I get an error for "(node:3631) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: message.channel.findEglibleForDeletion is not a function". Thanks for the fast reply BTW! :D

Comment: Did you put it in the textbased channel class?  if so, it should work the same as the bulk delete. Did you clear your cache?